# Information when user calling on emergency number

Tags: android

I need detect when user calling on Emergency number, like 112.

I read about NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and CALL_PRIVILEGED filter.

CALL_PRIVILEGED filter give permission to emergency call, but is no available for third-party apps. Anyone can tell me that, NEW_OUTGOING_CALL filter can give me information when user call on emergency number?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in android there are two ways to determine the call.

1.
[PhoneStateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

You **must** request (dangerous) permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

2.
Track the appearance of a new entry in CallLog by [ContentObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)

For example:

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
        true,
        YOUR_CallLog_Observer
);
```

You also need permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>`

See also [Requesting Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html).